# How to prove that n&(n-1) and n&(-n) respectively returns and removes the least significant bit?

Tags: bit-manipulation

In a code, I saw someone use:

`n&(n-1)` to get the least significant bit of `n` ⇒ 101000 will return 1000

`n&(-n)` to remove the lsb from `n` ⇒  101000 will return 100000.

This sounds magical to me. Is there any proof for these?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For $n=0b101000$ we have $n-1=0b100111$, so $n \& (n-1)=0b100000$.

As to the second, then knowing $-n=\sim n+1$ we have $-n= 0b10111 +1 = 0b11000$ so $n \& (-n)= 0b101000 \& 0b11000= 0b1000$.

**Addition for general proof**.

1. Let's take $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose $k$ is first one in its binary expansion i.e. $n=2^m a_m+ \cdots + 2^k a_k$, where $m \geqslant k$.Then
   $$n \& (-n) = 2^k$$
   proof: as we know $-n=\sim n+1$. So, first step, $\sim n$, gives inversion for each bit. Hence in bits lower then $k$ we will have ones and in bit $k$ we will have zero. Now adding $1$ gives all zeros in bits lower then $k$ and in bit $k$ we again have one, but all upper bits are reversed. So $-n$ have in all  bits more then $k$ reversed values with respect to $n$, which gives result.
2. Again let's take $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose $k$ is first one in its binary expansion i.e. $n=2^m a_m+ \cdots + 2^k a_k$, where $m \geqslant k$. If we consider $n-1$, then we get zero in $k$-th bit. So $n$ and $n-1$ have different coefficient only for bit $k$. This gives, that in
   $n \& (n-1)$ we have all coefficients same as in $n$ besides $k$-th bit is zero.